# TypeDescriptor and child elements

Tags: c#, list, propertydescriptor

This code:

```
foreach (PropertyDescriptor descriptor in TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(lst[0]))
{
   Console.WriteLine(descriptor.Name);
}
```

will write out the name of all the elements in my list. I.e. FirstName / LastName or what ever. How do I write out the children of an element? If my list had an element Cars, which had type and color of the car, how would I use TypeDescriptor to write out that also?

What I got at the moment is:

- FirstName
- Lastname
- Car

What I want is something like this:

- FirstName
- LastName
- Car: Toyota, Red
- Car: Mitsubishi, Green

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The `PropertyDescriptor`-class provides a method called `GetChildProperties(System.Object)`.
You should be able to pass a reference from your current object to the method and in return, receive another collections containing the child properties.
It might even make sense to inherit from this class as to obtain the full functionality.

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/szzsy8sb.aspx) for documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to check the object type, and then get its properties when it's the right type.

```
foreach (PropertyDescriptor descriptor in TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(lst[0]))
{
   Console.WriteLine(descriptor.Name);

   if(descriptor.PropertyType == typeof(Car))
   {
      foreach(var child in descriptor.GetChildProperties())
      {
          Console.WriteLine(child.Name);
      }
   }   

}
```

Comment: Seems that I can't use child.Name like that, and even as I now got the children, I can't find a way to get the Name of child1. I'm new to TypeDescriptor, so there might be something I'm missing out on here...

Comment: Try passing the descriptor into the GetChildProperties method.

Comment: Still no luck. Child contains ComponentType, IsReadOnly, PropertyType. Doesn't help passing lst[0].Cars either. And I also tried this with no luck; 

foreach (PropertyDescriptor des in TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(lst[0].Cars))

Answer (score 0):

Think I got it. As long as I have the type I need the children for (Cars) I can do like this:

```
    foreach (Car c in lst[0].Cars)
                {
                    PropertyInfo[] properties = car.GetType().GetProperties(); 
                    foreach (PropertyInfo item in properties)
                    {
                        string propertyName = item.Name;
                    }
                }
```